# Cant render component after "if" state check

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, i'm just starting with React, so i'm stuck with some stupid problems.
I want to check for currentPage statement and to render relevant component.
It was OK while i used variables, not statements. I think that i cant understand some basic stuff with this

```
  class Main extends Component {
  render() {
  function MainNavBar //code     
  function setCurrentPageState //code

  this.state = {
      currentPage : 'home'
  };

  function ActivePage() {

      if (this.state.currentPage == 'home'){
          return <HomePage />
      }
      //Other if statements
  }

return (
  <div className="app">
      <MainNavBar />
      <ActivePage/>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include your entire component and elaborate on what isn't working properly?

Comment: As a first step, I would try writing the condition like this: if (this.state.currentPage === 'home') 

Notice the tripe ===

Comment: Uh, i tried it, but the problem stills there

Comment: Can you include the error please?

Comment: There is no error, but components just dont render and i have empty page while i try to check currentPage state in ActivePage func. Even MainNavBar doesnt render. I think that i'm just missed smth simple and important. But it was OK while i used var instead of state.
Like this

`
function ActivePage() {
          var currentPage = 'home'
          if (currentPage == 'home'){
              return <HomePage />
          }
`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in some things, try this:

```
class Main extends Component {
  contructor(props){
    this.state = {
      currentPage : 'home'
    };
    this.setCurrentPageState = this.setCurrentPageState.bind(this);
  }
  renderActivePage() {
    if (this.state.currentPage == 'home'){
      return <HomePage />
    }
    //Other if statements
  }
  renderMainNavBar() {
    return <MainNavBar />
  }
  setCurrentPageState() {
    this.setState({currentPage: 'newPage'})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {this.renderMainNavBar()}
        {this.renderActivePage()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You should initialize `state` in component `constructor` and then you should set it with `this.setState`. try it, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code structure is incorrect and your question isn't clear to me .
few suggestions that comes to me :

*. move `this.state = {
      currentPage : 'home'
  };`

inside constructor () {}

*. use '===' and not == this checks equal value and equal type here [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)
*. Please go through https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html the docs, so you get clear with syntax .